# Bottom up Template MergeSort iterations

Tags: c++, templates, iteration, mergesort

So essentially, I trying to understand the iterative version of mergesort. I did some research and found out that bottom up mergesort is the way to go.

My problem is that my version of buttom up mergesort will not enter it's last loop (to merge everything together).

As an illustration if I were to merge the following words:

- pizza

  cookie

  pineapple

  apple

  banana

  pear

  orange

  lime

  grapes

  peach

I would get:

apple

banana

cookie

lime

orange

pear

pineapple

pizza

*grapes*

*peach*

As you can tell the last 2 elements are not sorted correctly. 
Here is my implementation:

```
template <class T>
int mergesort(T arr[], int len)
{
    int currSize; //current sie of subarrays to be merged
                  //currSize varies from 1 to n/2
    int leftStart;//for picking start index of left subarray to be merged
    int count = 0;//barometer 

    //merge subarrays in bottom up manner. First merge subarrays of size 1.
    //then create sorted subarrays of size 2, then merge subarrays of size 2.
    //create sorted subarrays of size 4, and so on.
    for(currSize=1; currSize<=len-1; currSize = 2*currSize)
    {
        //picking starting point of different subarrays respective to its current size
        for(leftStart=0; leftStart<len-1; leftStart+=2*currSize)
        {
            //find ending point of left subarray
            //mid + 1 is starting point from the right
            int rightEnd = Min(leftStart+2*currSize-1,len-1);

            int mid = leftStart + (rightEnd - leftStart)/2;
            cout << "current size = " << currSize << endl;
            cout << leftStart << " + (" << rightEnd << " - " << leftStart << ") / 2 = " << mid << endl ; 

            //merge subarrays arr[leftStart...mid] & arr[mid+1...rightEnd]
            merge(arr,leftStart,mid,rightEnd,count);

        }   
    }
    return count;
}
```

Any idea on what's wrong would be greatly appreciated!

p.s This is my first time posting on stack overflow.

Comment: You work on chunks of elements whose left and right boundaries are always a power of two. Once you progress to size `4`, the last two elements are never looked at again.

Answer (score 0):

Try the example code below. merge() will need to be changed so that mid and rightEnd are the ending indices instead of the last indices. I also removed the references to count and changed mergesort() to not return anything.

It would be faster to do a one time allocation of the temp array, and change the direction of merge based on the pass. To avoid a copy pass, the number of passes could be determined at the start and if odd, the first pass could swap pairs of elements in place so that the merge sort would start with currSize = 2 and the sorted data would end up in arr[].

```
template <class T>
void mergesort(T arr[], int len)
{
    int currSize; //current sie of subarrays to be merged
                  //currSize varies from 1 to n/2
    int leftStart;//for picking start index of left subarray to be merged

    //merge subarrays in bottom up manner. First merge subarrays of size 1.
    //then create sorted subarrays of size 2, then merge subarrays of size 2.
    //create sorted subarrays of size 4, and so on.
    for(currSize = 1; currSize <= len; currSize = 2*currSize)
    {
        // picking starting point of different subarrays respective to its current size
        for(leftStart = 0; leftStart < len; leftStart += 2*currSize)
        {
            // set mid point, break if only one run remaining
            int mid = leftStart+currsize;
            if(mid >= len)
                break;
            // set rightEnd
            int rightEnd = min(mid+currSize, len);
            //merge subarrays arr[leftStart...mid-1] & arr[mid...rightEnd-1]
            merge(arr,leftStart,mid,rightEnd);
        }   
    }
}
```